# Eagle library files for FAN5109 or LM5100

Tags: eaglecad, gate-driving

Question 1 - Which is a better high side gate driver out of FAN5109 and LM5100?

Question 2 - If I am only using the driver as a high side gate driver, what should I do with the Low side pins(Both input pins and output pins)?

Question 3 - If FAN5109 only uses one PWM signal to generate signals for both high and low side gate, Do i assume that the two PWM's are complementary? (Ex. If one is 60%, will the other will be 40%?)

Question 4 - Where can i find the library files for either of the two gate drivers for creating a schematic on Eagle?

Answer (score 1):

Answer of Question 4:

Download libraries from element14 from here:
http://www.element14.com/community/thread/36914/l/element-14-all-cad-files

In which under "NSC_By_element14_Batch_1.1.lbr", you'll find LM5100.

Suket